# Printing from Cordova android emulator

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-code, ionic5

I am running an android emulator from the most recent visual studio code. I am using geolocation to record speed values of the physical device I am emulating on. I want to be able to print out an array I create from these speed values, but when I use console.log nothing happens. I am curious how to set this up correctly, please let me know!

Comment: You're running the emulator from visual studio, or do you mean android studio? I'm wondering if you're not running your app in debug mode in android studio?

Comment: Visual studio for sure, I just set it up to run through visual studio

Comment: It uses android studio for android sdk, but I am running the project and displaying it in my phone through visual studio

Comment: OK. Does the info at the bottom of this page about debugging help at all? https://androidemulator.org/emulators/visual-studio-android-emulator/